# Tile KDE Desktop

Tags: kde

Is there a way to automatically give each window (app) equal space in a KDE desktop, like Tiling in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

KDE does not have the native tiling feature you're after, you may want to look into a tiling window manager like [**xmonad**](http://xmonad.org/) or [**ratpoison**](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/), or use the built-in workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

[Bug 165933](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165933) deals with tiling several windows. It's not reimplemented yet in KDE 4.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but a tiling window manager is coming in KDE 4.5, here's a [demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faOQAgapQYQ). An early version is already avaiable if you are brave.

Answer (score 0):

kwin in KDE 4.5+ has native tiling support.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Window Behaviour** in your KDE menu. Look around the tabs for the check box that tells KWin to tile your windows.