# Is it possible to configure Kde 4 to resize windows to half desktop size when moved to the side of the screen?

Tags: linux, debian, kde, kde-4

In Windows 7 You can drag a window to the edge of the screen (the mouse pointer must touch the edge), windows offers you to resize the window to exactly half of the screen size. This is actually very handy on the wide screen monitors.

Is it possible (and how) to configure Kde 4 to do the same thing?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/52600#77999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a feature in the upcoming kde4.4 out february 9th.
http://linuxology.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/yes-we-can-kde-aero-snap-like/

Answer (score 9):

**How to bind a keyboard event in KDE 4.8 to a window move/resize action:**

```
System Settings => Shortcuts and Gestures => Global Keyboard Shortcuts
```

Choose KDE component: KWin

Scroll down to "Quick Tile Window to the Left / Right." you can assign a keyboard shortcut to that.  The one for windows 7 is Meta + right arrow.

Click Apply.

**Test:**

Press Meta+right arrow, the window snaps to the right of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

**KDE** already has that feature (4.4 and newer). Just drag the windows the way you used to in Windows 7. In fact KDE can let you tile *four* windows on the same screen at the same time, something Windows 7 doesn't have.